# Google goggles API

Tags: android, google-goggles

Does anyone know if there is a google goggles API for Android? If not, is there one coming any time soon? With an API for this thing the possibilities are endless...

So far all I've been able to find on this subject is a discussion about not currently having a version for the iPhone due to it's "google labs" status (iPhone version coming once it's more "complete"). I'm hoping an API may be released then. Anybody have any info on this at all?

Comment: Hey Russell, this blog post discusses some of the Goggles API. Let me know if you have any questions. http://notanothercodeblog.blogspot.com/2011/02/google-goggles-api.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google Goggles to Become App Platform
http://phandroid.com/2010/04/14/google-goggles-to-become-app-platform/

Comment: Thanks Damon. The original link looks to be this one: http://www.techradar.com/news/phone-and-communications/mobile-phones/google-we-plan-to-open-up-our-goggles-platform-683454

Answer (score 5):

Not an official API but this guy seems to have reversed engineered some of it.

http://notanothercodeblog.blogspot.com/2011/02/google-goggles-api.html

You may also want to try VisualSearchAPI.com, they have visual search APIs. See demo and docs here. http://www.visualsearchapi.com/demo/view?demo=1 and http://www.visualsearchapi.com/apiDoc/apiDoc?apiDoc=V

Answer (score 4):

Shameless, shameless plug:

There's also http://kooaba.com which offers Visual Search.

http://docs.kooaba.com for screencast, docs, api sample code etc.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that people are hardly waiting for this: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Mobile/thread?tid=16861855be946ceb&hl=en

Comment: Thanks. That's all I could find as well. I'm hoping someone might have some more info on if/when an API is being released. Without an API it's missing 99% of it's usefulness so it must be coming (I hope).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an open API for visual search (image recognition): http://www.iqengines.com/, see developer portal.

Comment: Thank you John, that looks interesting. I'll take a look when I get some spare time.

Comment: This one is pretty good if you are developing something on image recognition ...You get 999 queries free for sign up.

Comment: Apparently iqengines is not available anymore as it was bought out by Yahoo.  http://techcrunch.com/2013/08/23/yahoo-acquires-image-recognition-startup-iq-engines/