# API for Google Goggles or Visual Search?

Tags: image, api, google-api, google-goggles

Are there any APIs similar to Google Goggles that accepts a picture as input and outputs text descriptions?

In other words, we're looking for a visual search API.  if we submit photos, we want the service to say what the item is and provide a brief description ... similar to Google Goggles.

Does this exist?

Comment: Answer available here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080731/google-goggles-api

Comment: Hello, I made a scraper in PHP. It depends what information you want about the picture. If you need title or description, then you can get it from my xpath query and easily rewrite the code from PHP to Java. I made a blog post about that which is here http://skyzerblogger.blogspot.com/2013/01/google-reverse-image-search-scraping.html

Comment: [CloudSight.ai](http://cloudsight.ai/). It powers [CamFind](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/camfind-visual-search-powered-by-cloudsight-ai/id595857716?mt=8), among other apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this start-up with an image recognition API: http://developer.iqengines.com/

Comment: Note that the IQ Engines service has been acquired by Yahoo!, and is no longer accepting new developers.

Answer (score 5):

kooaba http://www.kooaba.com is actually one of the longest running image recognition platforms (started even before Goggles came out).

[EDIT: the URL is https://developer.vuforia.com (Qualcomm bought Kooaba in the year 2014)]

So this is another service you might give a shot.

Compared to recognize.im kooaba already databases you can use in addition to uploading your own.

Compared to iqengines, kooaba gives you nicely structured meta-data as a response, whereas for most things iqengines just gives a "tag".

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: I work for Recognize.im)

If you are still looking for an image recognition API, you could try out our platform at [www.recognize.im](http://www.recognize.im). You can upload your own image database and then when you send an image to the API, you will get the image id from your database. 
Best wishes!

Comment: is there a limit on the number of images