# Google Goggles Intent

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google goggles API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080731/google-goggles-api)

According to Google, Goggles now supports barcode scanning via intents.
So how would I launch this intent?
Apart from it being mentioned on the app store site there's no info whatsoever :(

Am I missing something trivial here?

Comment: I don't agree with this being closed, as the answer accepted here is completely different to the 'rumour' blog post mentioned in the accepted answer for the linked question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of ways, according to the Goggles manifest.

The app listens for the following intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
startActivity(intent);
```

This is the code you're looking for, which is basically the same information provided by [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent).

As an aside, you can also use a VIEW intent with path `http://www.google.com/m/products/scan` though this will offer both the browser and Goggles as handlers for the uri. This webpage actually recommends installing zxing's barcode scanner rather than Google Goggles.

Comment: thanks, that should do the trick, however it is odd that they name it the same as the ZXing's one. Maybe to choose the scanner upon scanning

Comment: Likely, and ZXing seems to have some relationship to Google. Either they created the project, or one of their developers is involved. There's a couple of @google.com addresses in the members list.