# There are many image search api. but how can i integrate one of them to my app for finding similar image ?

Tags: android, image, search

I want to integrate one of image search api for finding similar image like a google goggles do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Chrish -- Check this

http://www.technotalkative.com/android-google-image-search-api-example-json-parsing-web-api-call-demo/

visual search api for web and mobile here too: http://www.macroglossa.com/api.html. they provide custom services too.

Or just Check replies for this question

[Google goggles API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080731/google-goggles-api)

Comment: link is very useful when user want to search image by text not imageItself. i want to search image like what exactly google goggles do. infact i wan take picture from camera and want to search that image on web, which should return json so that i can proceed ahead. Is there any??? has anyone done before?

Comment: if people wan search image by typing a text on there app. In that case it might be very useful. so i am accepting it as an answer. but it doesnt match in my case. can any one suggest me over my problem??

Comment: hey chrish, did u find out a way to do it??

Answer (score 0):

IQ Engines offers an API that allows you to integrate image recognition into your mobile application. For more information see http://www.iqengines.com. If you sign up for a trial you get 1000 free visual scans and can download the iOS and Android SDKs. There's a Quick Start Guide http://www.iqengines.com/quickstart, API Documentation and README files for the SDKs that explain the process.