# Free image search API --- take an image with a camera and retrieve information about its contents

Tags: android, image, search, image-processing

I want to build an android app which allows users to take an image of an object using the camera and then search the Internet to find out more about the captured object.

The problem is I cannot find any suitable APIs or websites to handle the search. Is there any free API which allows image based search?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell in your answer, you want to search the web using an image (as in what you can do in Google). If that's the case, here's the link to another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940497/there-are-many-image-search-api-but-how-can-i-integrate-one-of-them-to-my-app-f) that poses a similar query.

Just to summarize the answer there,

> IQ Engines offers an API that allows you to integrate image
>   recognition into your mobile application. For more information see
>   http://www.iqengines.com. If you sign up for a trial you get 1000 free
>   visual scans and can download the iOS and Android SDKs. There's a
>   Quick Start Guide http://www.iqengines.com/quickstart, API
>   Documentation and README files for the SDKs that explain the process.