# Google image search by image in android

Tags: android, google-image-search

Is there any API in android for search image from google by uploading image from my android application ?

For Example,We search image by uploading on google.

Answer (score 2):

You can use google goggle's API for search images by search instead of keyword..

here is some link for that..

[Link 1](http://notanothercodeblog.blogspot.in/2011/02/google-goggles-api.html)

[All Google API](https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:596254687690:services)

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080731/google-goggles-api)