# Getting an ISBN from an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, isbn

I can launch the google goggles app as a user, not with an intent, and get the isbn of a book from a picture of the front cover.  I can also launch goggles from an intent and scan the barcode of a book.  What I am looking for is the ability to launch an intent that will return the isbn of a book based on a picture of it's front cover.  Does any app offer this ability?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google goggles API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080731/google-goggles-api)

Comment: It might be a duplicate of that one, but that question has no concrete answer and has had no activity for several years. I was hoping that some intents for Google glass had been published and I dust unable to find them. Or that someone else provided this feature now.